# Dos formularios con dos botones independientes (HTML)

Tags: php, html, formularios, pdf

Estoy implementando un formulario que casi lo tengo acabado, pero tengo problemas con la parte final. Primeramente el formulario consta de dos "radio buttons" siendo **Solicitud** y **Nuevo miembro** respectivamente.

Cuando se selecciona una opción u otra, más abajo se carga unos campos u otros del formulario para que el usuario los rellene y luego pulse en el botón de 'Enviar'. Por otro lado, tengo dos archivos: **solicitud.php** y **miembro.php**, en que cada uno debería recoger de forma independiente los datos introducidos en el formulario. Cada .php crea un documento pdf distinto con la librería mPDF y lo envía a un correo como documento adjunto.

Cada instancia, de forma independiente, funciona correctamente, se genera bien el PDF y se envía por correo como documento adjunto. El problema que tengo es a la hora de unificar el formulario en un mismo HTML con la conmutación de los radio buttons.

Una manera que se me ha ocurrido es hacerlo así:

**HTML**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function displayForm(c) {
    if (c.value == "2") {    
        jQuery('#memberForm').toggle('show');
        jQuery('#requestForm').hide();
    }
        if (c.value == "1") {
         jQuery('#requestForm').toggle('show');
         jQuery('#memberForm').hide();
    }
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>Solicitud
    <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>Miembro
   


    <tr>
        <td><div style="display:none" id="requestForm">
            <form id="request" action="formulari.php" method="POST"> 
            <label>Reserva :</label>
            <input type="text" id="reserva" name="reserva" value="$reserva">
            <br>
            <p>Horario :
                <input type="text" id="horario" name="horario" value="$horario">
            </p>
            <p>Participantes :
                <input type="text" id="participantes" name="participantes" value="$participantes">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Enviar">
        </form>
        </div></td>
    
        <td><div style="display:none" id="memberForm">
            <form id="member" action="formulari2.php" method="POST">
            <p>Nombre y apellidos
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="$name">
            </p>
            <p>
            E-mail :
            <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" value="$mail">
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    
    </tr>


</form>


</body>
<html>
```

Pero sólo se me ejecuta el segundo radio button correctamente. También había pensado en unificar ambos .php, pero busco la manera en que estén separados ya que así no debería tocar tanto código y quedaría más 'limpio'.

¿Alguien puede indicarme?

Un saludo

Comment: Es posible usar un formulario dentro de otro???

Comment: @Caliche No. Es HTML no válido que acaba teniendo resultados inesperados.

Answer (score 1):

Al final encontré la solución, y era un detalle estúpido pero que no lo vi... El error fue que añadí sin darme cuenta los dos forms dentro de un form genérico. Al quitarlos de ese form global, funcionó!

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Ambos formularios están bien, pues dentro del **form action** son diferentes, la razón por la que debe estar fallando y quizá NO notaste es en `value="Enviar"` pues ambos formularios tienen la misma :/ ¿Podrías probar cambiándolas? `value="Enviar"` y `value="Enviar2"` por ejemplo?

Comment: Probé lo que me comentas y no era eso. Al final encontré la solución (lo he comentado como respuesta). Muchas gracias por tu comentario.